# SQL - self join 'n' times with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I have the following table:

```
Id                                    | Type
--------------------------------------------
C1C1A90D-B131-4450-B1BF-5041F36F9144  |  1
C7B1752D-FD30-445A-AD6C-51D1434607D3  |  2
3AAF8BB6-A6D4-4780-BEF9-ACBBF75A85DE  |  3
--------------------------------------------
67EF1537-A22E-4D2D-AAEA-FC0D9E2B9912  |  1
546519ED-5E78-4DAD-ADFF-9DC0AA67B763  |  2
8F66A3F9-C652-4758-8E17-B4DE0B0D85A4  |  3
--------------------------------------------
-- ... and so on ... --
```

Now, I need a specific type of **SELECT** (something like this):

```
SELECT
    [Id] AS [OneId]   -- Where [Type] = 1,
    [Id] AS [TwoId]   -- Where [Type] = 2,
    [Id] AS [ThreeId] -- Where [Type] = 3
FROM Table
```

This is what I've tried so far but with bad results:

```
SELECT
    oneI.[Id] AS [OneId]   -- Where [Type] = 1,
    twoI.[Id] AS [TwoId]   -- Where [Type] = 2,
    threeI.[Id] AS [ThreeId] -- Where [Type] = 3
FROM Table AS i
INNER JOIN Table AS oneI ON
    i.[Id] = oneI.[Id]
INNER JOIN Table AS twoI ON
    i.[Id] = twoI.[Id]
INNER JOIN Table AS threeI ON
    i.[Id] = threeI.[Id]
WHERE 
    oneI.[Type] = 1
AND twoI.[Type] = 2
AND threeI.[Type] = 3
```

Or even worse (which gave me more lots of combinations):

```
SELECT
    oneI.[Id] AS [OneId]   -- Where [Type] = 1,
    twoI.[Id] AS [TwoId]   -- Where [Type] = 2,
    threeI.[Id] AS [ThreeId] -- Where [Type] = 3
FROM Table AS i, TABLE AS oneI, Table AS twoI, Table AS threeI
WHERE 
    oneI.[Type] = 1
AND twoI.[Type] = 2
AND threeI.[Type] = 3
```

> ***EDIT:***

I would also have another column on which I would group those Ids. So the updated table look like:

```
Id                                               | GroupId | Type
------------------------------------------------------------------
C1C1A90D-B131-4450-B1BF-5041F36F9144  -- OneId   |    1    |  1 
C7B1752D-FD30-445A-AD6C-51D1434607D3  -- TwoId   |    1    |  2 
3AAF8BB6-A6D4-4780-BEF9-ACBBF75A85DE  -- ThreeId |    1    |  3 
------------------------------------------------------------------
67EF1537-A22E-4D2D-AAEA-FC0D9E2B9912 -- OneId    |    2    |  1 
546519ED-5E78-4DAD-ADFF-9DC0AA67B763 -- TwoId    |    2    |  2 
8F66A3F9-C652-4758-8E17-B4DE0B0D85A4 -- ThreeId  |    2    |  3 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, I would need the following result:

```
OneI   | TwoI  | ThreeI   | GroupId
------------------------------------------------------
OneId  | TwoId | ThreeId  |    1
OneId  | TwoId | ThreeId  |    2
```

> ***EDIT:***

I have one more special case - `[Type]` column can repeat:

```
Id                                                    | GroupId | Type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
C1C1A90D-B131-4450-B1BF-5041F36F9144  -- OneId        |    1    |  1 
C7B1752D-FD30-445A-AD6C-51D1434607D3  -- TwoId        |    1    |  2 
3AAF8BB6-A6D4-4780-BEF9-ACBBF75A85DE  -- ThreeId      |    1    |  3 
FEB4A345-FEA0-4530-AE52-6CF4F07E37BA  -- OtherThreeId |    1    |  3 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
67EF1537-A22E-4D2D-AAEA-FC0D9E2B9912 -- OneId         |    2    |  1 
546519ED-5E78-4DAD-ADFF-9DC0AA67B763 -- TwoId         |    2    |  2 
8F66A3F9-C652-4758-8E17-B4DE0B0D85A4 -- ThreeId       |    2    |  3 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And now the result would be:

```
OneI   | TwoI  | ThreeI        | GroupId
------------------------------------------------------
OneId  | TwoId | ThreeId       |    1
OneId  | TwoId | OtherThreeId  |    1
OneId  | TwoId | ThreeId       |    2
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a1c7)

Comment: If the results are like in groups of 3, they must have some kind of common discriminator from other groups.

Comment: Did you try `union`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this would required some sequential ordering columns, but you could also express this as

```
select max(case when [Type] = 1 then Id end) OneId,
       max(case when [Type] = 2 then Id end) TwoId,
       max(case when [Type] = 3 then Id end) ThreeId
from (select *, 
             row_number() over (order by (select 1)) Seq 
      from table
     ) t
group by (Seq - [Type]);
```

**EDIT :-** However, if you want to include `group` also then use them as in select statement as

```
select (Seq - [Type]) as GroupId,
       max(case when [Type] = 1 then 'OneId' end) OneI,
       max(case when [Type] = 2 then 'TwoId' end) TwoI,
       max(case when [Type] = 3 then 'ThreeId' end) ThreeI
from (select *, 
             row_number() over (order by (select 1)) Seq 
      from table
      ) t
group by (Seq - [Type]);
```

For your updated table you can directly use table with `group by` clause with your `GroupId`  column as then you don't use `row_number()` function  and subquery

```
select max(case when [Type] = 1 then 'OneId' end) OneI,
       max(case when [Type] = 2 then 'TwoId' end) TwoI,
       max(case when [Type] = 3 then 'ThreeId' end) ThreeI,
       GroupId
from table t
group by GroupId;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c2a5/12)

Comment: i need GroupId (it's value) insted of row number

Comment: @jovanM... Changing the question after asking it is rude. Btw, check my edit.

Comment: still not the expected result from my last edit in the question - I'm still missing a row for the Id with the duplicated [Type]

Comment: yea, sry for the edit, i'm doing multiple tasks at once and couldn't keep a track what i needed exactly...

Comment: @jovanM... Whenever, you make an edit,  and after people look at answer then it would attract  the down-vote. So, it would be always better to ask other question with new edits.

Comment: Sharma, I just added condition to a queestion - i didn't change the question from the root. My question is still the same at the base...

Comment: thnks, but still i need ids instead of nulls - as in the result table in my last edit..

Comment: hey, i still got slight problem with the select... if i add another row with same type - query again returns null for some ids. here's the [sqlfiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c2a5/1)

Comment: @jovanM... Oh yes that would not come in my mind corrected check [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0c2a5/12)

Answer (score 2):

You need an `Grp` attribute then specifies which rows are together in one group. Something like this

```
Id                                    | Type |  Grp
----------------------------------------------------
C1C1A90D-B131-4450-B1BF-5041F36F9144  |  1   |   1
C7B1752D-FD30-445A-AD6C-51D1434607D3  |  2   |   1
3AAF8BB6-A6D4-4780-BEF9-ACBBF75A85DE  |  3   |   1
---------------------------------------------------
67EF1537-A22E-4D2D-AAEA-FC0D9E2B9912  |  1   |   2
546519ED-5E78-4DAD-ADFF-9DC0AA67B763  |  2   |   2
8F66A3F9-C652-4758-8E17-B4DE0B0D85A4  |  3   |   2
--------------------------------------------------
```

Then you can use conditional aggregation like this

```
SELECT
     MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN [Id] END) AS [OneId],
     MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN [Id] END) AS [TwoId],
     MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 3 THEN [Id] END) AS [ThreeId]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Grp
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this would do the job for you

```
; WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    Id,
    [Type]
    FROM YourTable
       WHERE [Type]
       IN
       (
          1,2,3,4,5
       )
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
    PIVOT
    (
       MAX(id)
       FOR [Type] IN
       (
          [1],[2],[3],[4],[5]
       )
    )Pvt
```

Comment: this grouped them, but only the first group - it only returned one row - first group from the sample table in my question